# Laravel 5 - Error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::fire()

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I'm working on a REST API using JWT.

The login route is good, but the router in group `middleware jwt.auth` doesn't work.

Error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::fire()

My code:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function(){

    Route::get('user/login', 'AuthController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {            
        Route::get('auth/me', 'AuthController@me');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

`fire` was changed to `dispatch` in laravel **5.8** here https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26392

Answer (score 2):

If you use `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` package, this issue help you : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1787

This version fix this problem : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc.4

Answer (score 1):

The `Event` method `fire` is deprecated in Laravel v5.8 However it works on prior version of Laravel v5.7
You can use the method `dispatch` in Laravel v5.8 and later. It works same as `fire` method and dispatches the event to event handler function registered in `EventServiceProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Changed fire() to dispatch() for Laravel 5.8+

Answer (score 0):

> JWT still using fire method and it's replced with dispatch method in
>   Laravel 5.8  so the solution should change the method call in JWT.

this solution worked with me on Laravel 5.8

go to this path in your project

```
\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Middleware\GetUserFromToken.php
```

this is the original code:

```
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
    }

    try {
        $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.expired', 'token_expired', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.invalid', 'token_invalid', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    }

    if (! $user) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.user_not_found', 'user_not_found', 404);
    }

    $this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);

    return $next($request);
}
```

and you should change:

`$this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user)`

to:

`$this->events->dispatch('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);`

you only replace `fire` method with `dispatch` because `fire` method is not available in Laravel 5.8 and the newest way is using `dispatch` method.

I hope this solution working with you..

Comment: You should never edit anything in `vendor`. It'll go away with the next `composer update`, or with a deployment. You should update `tymon/jwt-auth` instead - the more recent releases work in Laravel 5.8 just fine.

Comment: I just install JWT now it's updated ..
I only make change inside `tymon/jwt-auth` and it's will not go away after `composer update`

I hope you give me another solution if you have ?

Answer (score 0):

When update laravel to 5.8, have some note:

> **The fire Method Likelihood Of Impact: *Low***
>
> The fire method (**which was deprecated in Laravel 5.4**) of the
>   **Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher** class has been **removed**. You should **use
>   the dispatch** method instead.

See more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#events

With old jwt, they use fire method so your code is error. Follow & Fix it:

**Update Jwt to new version -> 1.0.0-rc.4**

> Add "**tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.4**" to your composer.json file AND run
>   "**composer update**"

```
Ex: "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.4"
    },
```

See more: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

-> In **Model Users** add new code:

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
```

-> In **config/jwt.php** change **providers** to

```
'jwt' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi',
'auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate',
'storage' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate',
```

-> In **config/auth.php** change **guards** to

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Passport Solution on Version 5.8**

I was using `Laravel Passport` and faced the same issue, in my case in the  `vendor/laravel/passsport/src/Bridge/RefreshTokenRepository.php` file, on line 71 changed the `$this->events->fire(...)` method name to `$this->events->dispatch(...)` This trick solved the issue and I could get the token.